# Os Customization when deploying from vShpere Content library

Tags: ansible

I'm using the `community.vmware.vmware_content_deploy_ovf_template` [link][1] module to deploy a vm from a template in a content library.
With the `vmware_guest` module, you can apply a `customization` when cloning.

However this seems to be missing when using the content library.
I figured one should use `vmware_guest` module after deploying from the content library, with `existing_vm: yes` parameter in the `customization` spec, but this didn't work:

ansible just checks whether the machine is powered on, and skips the customization entirely.

*Update:
My current workaround is to deploy a VM from the library first, and then use the vmguest_clone to clone my vms from that one.
[1]: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_content_deploy_ovf_template_module.html#ansible-collections-community-vmware-vmware-content-deploy-ovf-template-module